# Take screenshot when application crashes in Android

Tags: android, android-framework

I am developing a Bug Reporter in my custom ROM and want to know if there is a mechanism of taking screenshot when an application has crashed.

I know that **`handleApplicationCrash()`** method of `ActvityManagerService` is called when an application crashes. From here an Intent with action Intent.`ACTION_APP_ERROR` is broadcasted which contains `BUG_REPORT`.

I also know that **`BugReportReceiver`** in *frameworks/base/packages/Shell* also gets Intent with extras `EXTRA_BUG_REPORT` and `EXTRA_SCREENSHOT`. But I am not able to trace from where screenshot is generated and this Intent is broadcast.

I need help in writing code to take a screenshot automatically when an application has crashed.

Answer (score -2):

f you want to save information about the app crash, you must go with [acra library](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a Google Doc form. It is targeted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously. (Taken from link)

A crash reporting feature for android apps is native since Android 2.2 (FroYo) but only available through the official Android Market (and with limited data). ACRA is a great help for Android developers :

I hope this should help you...

Comment: ACRA is meant for individual application crash reporting. I am making modifications in framework code for my ROM, and I want to intercept all application crashes. I am able to do that but I want to know how I can get a screenshot of app crash also.

Comment: Also which native feature are you referring to? Can you please share details on that.